# delete Style in Execl Using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I created Excel file using this code:

```
Sheets worksheets = wb.Sheets;
Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)worksheets[4];
int rows = dt.Rows.Count;
int columns = dt.Columns.Count;
var data = new object[rows + 1, columns];

for (var column = 0; column < columns; column++)
{
  data[0, column] = dt.Columns[column].ColumnName;
}

for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++)
{
  for (var column = 0; column < columns; column++)
  {
    data[row + 1, column] = dt.Rows[row][column];
  }
}

Range beginWrite = (Range)worksheet.Cells[1, 1];
Range endWrite = (Range)worksheet.Cells[rows + 1, columns];
Range sheetData = worksheet.Range[beginWrite, endWrite];
sheetData.Value2 = data;
worksheet.Select();
sheetData.Worksheet.ListObjects.Add(XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange,
  sheetData,
  Type.Missing,
  XlYesNoGuess.xlNo,
  Type.Missing);

sheetData.Select();
Excel.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = false;
Excel.Application.Range["2:2"].Select();
Excel.Application.Range["$A$3"].Select();
```

the problem here it set default format style to excel file
I don't know how to clear all  format style in excel sheet

Comment: What do you mean with "format style"? At what lines does your code fail? - More information needed.

Comment: Design of table

Comment: my code doesn't fail but it set different design to my excel file so i want to delete that style

Answer (score 1):

If all you are trying to do is delete all styles, this would work:

```
using Excelx = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excelx.Workbook wb = excel.ActiveWorkbook;

foreach (Excelx.Style st in wb.Styles)
    st.Delete();
```

Then again, you may only want to clear out custom styles (not the ones that come standard), in which case a small modification would do it:

```
foreach (Excelx.Style st in wb.Styles)
{
    if (!st.BuiltIn)
        st.Delete();
}
```

Styles are stored at the workbook level, so at some point you need to declare your workbook.  From there, the `Styles` collection of the Workbook object has everything you need.